# How to create a object of variables, and return it, in Python?

Tags: python

How is it possible to create an object in Python, and return this object to use within another method?

In PHP i can do it like this:

```
$disk->test1 = 'value'
$disk->test2 = 'value1'
$disk->test3 = 'value2'

$clientObj->createDisk(array('diskname'=>$disk));
```

How would you do this in the best possible way, in Python?

EDIT:
I ended up using the always good solution; dictionaries.

Comment: Define "best". There are several options for structuring data in Python; which is most appropriate depends on your needs and preferences.

Comment: Just what you individually think is best. I am open for all suggestions. I need a piece similar to the PHP snippet i pasted.

Comment: Well that is inevitably opinion-based, so I'm voting to close as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class:

```
class Disk(object):
    def __init__(self, test1=None, test2=None, test3=None):
        self.test1 = test1
        self.test2 = test2
        self.test3 = test3
```

And then create an instance of it:

```
mydist = Disk()
mydist.test1 = "value"
# And so on
```

You could also use a dictionary (for your example):
    disk = {}
    disk["test1"] = "value"
    disk["test2"] = "value1"
    disk["test3"] = "value2"

Unlike PHP and Javascript, Python isn't a [Prototype-Based Language.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) This means you have to define classes to create objects, and you can't create generic "object" instances and add properties which weren't in the class definition.

You can, however, add properties to instances of your own classes. For example:

```
class Example(object):
    pass

myobject = Example()
myobject.a = "value"
```

Comment: *"you can't create generic "object" instances and add properties which weren't in the class definition"* - yes you can!

Comment: ...yes, you can. Try `myobject.foo = 'bar'`.

Comment: If your'e talking about modifying the `__dict__` property, then you're still wrong, because generic object() instances don't have a `__dict__` property!

Comment: If you mean specifically `myobject = object()` then you're correct, but that's not what your example shows. `myobject.a` only fails because you haven't assigned it yet; you can add attributes to either the instance `myobject` or the class `Example` dynamically.

Comment: I fixed it. You used to not be able to do that, and I haven't tried since. Sorry about calling you wrong!

Comment: Not a problem, perhaps be a little more diplomatic in future!